# Groovy break out of outer switch from nested switch (not in loop)?

Tags: groovy, nested, switch-statement

`switch` statements in Groovy are infinitely more flexible, powerful and applicable than in Java. For this reason I've just found myself wanting to use a nested `switch` for the first time in Groovy.

With this:

```
outerSwitch:
switch( var1 ){
    case 'x': 
        ...
        break
    case 'y':
        switch( var2 ){
            case 'a':
            // something
            break outerSwitch
            ...
        }
    ...
}
```

... I get a horrid message from the Groovy compiler saying "Groovy: the break statement with named label is only allowed inside loops".  I don't know whether this is the same with Java.

There is an obvious silly workaround: you enclose your outer `switch` with a `while( true )`, apply the `outerSwitch` label to that, and put a `break` statement at the end of your outer `switch`.

Or you could do a `for( int i = 0; i < 1; i++ )` ... or use a Groovy-er idiom for the same thing, I forget what all the options are... although having tried

```
outerSwitch:
1.times{
    switch( var1 ){
        ...
}
```

... I find that the Groovy compiler gives the same nasty message. So you can't fool it with a closure, seemingly.

Is there anything in the Groovy toolkits and boxes of tricks which lets you jump out of the outer `switch` from the nested `switch` more sensibly?

The trouble being, I suppose, that when you `break` from a `case` block you don't do so with a value... if you could go `break true` or `break 'fiddle-de-dee'` there'd be obvious ways to solve this.

An obvious workaround is that you can precede your nested `switch` with `def breakouter = false` and then change that as applicable in the `case` block. I'd just hope that Groovy would provide something more elegant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the break behavior but if refactoring your switch statement is an option, perhaps the following could work:

```
def var1 = "y"
def var2 = "a" 

switch ([var1, var2]) {
  case { it.first() == "x"}: 
    println "var1 == 'x'"
    break

  case [['y', 'a']]:
    println "var1 == 'y', var2 == 'a'"
    break

  default: 
    println "something else"
}
```

where the first case condition is a closure which will execute the case if it returns true and the second is a list of lists which will execute the case if the outer list contains the value.

This code essentially replicates the functionality in your original code snippet but with a flat switch structure. Breaking with labels, even if it worked, is in my mind not a good pattern.

Output:

```
~> groovy test.groovy 

var1 == 'y', var2 == 'a'
```

Comment: Thanks... yes, agree about labels.  The idea of a hierarchy of `switch` statements, to my mind, was when this seemed naturally desirable, in terms of the problem.  But maybe instead of such a "naked" (and potentially very large) multi-`switch` structure it'd be better to call methods in the outer `switch`'s `case` blocks.  Each of these could then return a value which could be acted on: so the "inner" `switch` case blocks might call `return x` rather than `break`.  I was probably mis-thinking it!